# servlet with tomcat v5.5.30

Tags: eclipse, servlets

I created a simple dynamic web-project and put all the required entries in web.xml and index.html and one servlet class file in WEB-INF/classes folder, when I attempt to run application, the server is not starting and showing a Error pop-up showing"Server tomcat v5.5 is unable to start within 45 second, If the server require the more time ,try increasing the timeout in server editor".I am using Tomcat v5.5 server at localhost and eclipse-helios. Maybe it is a dumb question, but I am not unable to run my application.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to run tomcat from eclipse, this is how you can increase the server timeout.

Click on window->show view->servers, then double click on your server and click on Timeouts.

by the way, why did you put the servlet inside classes folder? generally you put your source (any java class) inside src folder and set the build path (right click project->java build path->Source) so that the output of compilation b eclipses goes to classes or bin folder.

Comment: Hey I also increase timeout of server, but it is not helping so.Can u please tell, why this type of error popup is showing,thanks for telling additional information about classes foler,but when I run the servlet on server the .class file goes to classes foler,but if I delete tha classes then it is deleting only in eclipse, if I see .class manually in particular drive(where workspace remain) the .class is exist, please tell me why this is happing,thanks in advance for helping me..:)

Comment: Can you post the server logs? What do you mean by running the servlet on server (compiling or running the server?). If you delete any classes in eclipse, it asks whether to delete from disk also (can not be undone), until you select this disk files will not be deleted. Generally you should clean the project and rebuild in eclipse instead of deleting manually.